# let $S_n=a_1+a_2+…+a_n$ If $a_1=2010$ and $S_n=n^2a_n$ for all $n$, what is the value of $a_{2010}$?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

There is a list of numbers $a_1
, a_2,a_3,…,a_{2010}$.  For  $1\le n \le 2010$, where $n$ is a positive integer, let $S_n=a_1+a_2+…+a_n$ If $a_1=2010$ and $S_n=n^2a_n$ for all $n$, what is the value of $a_{2010}$?

Im not sure how to solve this, I think you could derive a formula of some sort that could be used to solve it but im not sure how to do that.

Hints aswell as solutions would be appreciated

*taken from the 2010 IWYMIC*
https://chiuchang.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/02/2010-IWYMIC-Individual.x17381.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_1=2010$ and 
$$ S_n = n^2(S_n-S_{n-1})$$
imply
$$ S_n = \frac{n^2}{n^2-1} S_{n-1} = S_1\prod_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k^2}{k^2-1} $$
so
$$a_{2010} = \frac{S_{2010}}{2010^2} = \frac{1}{2010}\prod_{k=2}^{2010}\frac{k\cdot k}{(k-1)\cdot(k+1)}=\frac{2010!\cdot2010!}{2010\cdot2009!\cdot2011!/2}=\frac{2}{2011}. $$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*. Notice that $a_{n+1} = S_{n+1} - S_n$, therefore
$$a_{n+1} = (n+1)^2 a_{n+1} - n^2 a_n$$
from which we get that
$$a_{n+1} = \frac n {n+2}\, a_n$$
From this, can you find $a_n$ in terms of $a_1$?